# Does Wifi data between devices go through router?

Tags: wireless-networking

When transferring file using wifi between 2 devices, say between a computer and a smartphone.  Does every package need to go through the wifi router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all the traffic flows through the router.  Devices connect to the router, not to each other.  The router acts like a post office, receiving the packets and delivering them to the proper address.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?